# What does a disparity map in OpenCV tell?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, disparity-mapping

What does the map returned by `stereo.compute()` indicate?

The definition of disparity is the distance between two comparable pixels in the left and right images.
However, by running the following code, I obtained a map with the same size as the input photos with values ranging from `-16` to `211`. I got confused when it comes with some negative numbers. If these values refer to distance, why would a distance of `-16` be possible? (In fact, it has plenty of `-16` in the map).
What precisely do these values indicate?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**code:**

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

imgL = cv.imread("data/stereo-corridor_l.png", 0)
print(imgL.shape)
imgR = cv.imread("data/stereo-corridor_r.png", 0)

stereo = cv.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=17)
disparity = stereo.compute(imgL, imgR)

plt.imshow(disparity, "gray")
plt.show()
```

**two images used:**
stereo right
[image: image R]
stereo left
[image: image L]

Comment: The distance is directional: if for example you get positive values when the pixel in `imgR` is to the **right** of pixel in `imgL`, then a negative value means it is to the **left** of it (it could be the other way around, I don't remember which is the actual case).

Comment: In stereo vision you cannot have negative disparity, as an object seen from your left eye can never be more to the left when seen from the right eye.
The value `-1` stands for unmatched area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per its [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d2/d6e/classcv_1_1StereoMatcher.html#a03f7087df1b2c618462eb98898841345), `stereo.compute()` computes *16-bit fixed-point disparity map (where each disparity value has 4 fractional bits), whereas other algorithms output 32-bit floating-point disparity map.*

In practice this means that the numbers your are having are integers that must be converted to floating point values.

With some little changes, I did:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

imgL = cv.imread("data/stereo-corridor_l.png", 0)
print(imgL.shape)
imgR = cv.imread("data/stereo-corridor_r.png", 0)

stereo = cv.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=17)
disparity = stereo.compute(imgL, imgR).astype(np.float32)/16

print(f"Range: {np.min(disparity)} <-> {np.max(disparity)}")

plt.imshow(disparity, "gray")
plt.show()
```

You can see that the disparity range is `-1.0 <-> 12.5625`, where -1 simply means that the matching algorithm couldn't find a matching correspondence.

Instead, without the conversion `astype(np.float32)/16`, you would get a fake range of `-16 <-> 201`, which is wrong and also 201 is a too high value (you don't have objects so close).

For a full example you may refer to my [code here](https://github.com/decadenza/SimpleStereo/blob/master/examples/008%20StereoMatchingSGBM.py), as part of the [SimpleStereo library](https://github.com/decadenza/SimpleStereo).